# Dynamodb. How to put-item conditional on two unique attributes where one is hash key?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I am really not understanding at all how dynamodb's condition expression is supposed to work and I can't find any relief reading the documentation or searching for examples.

In the runnable below I am trying to only permit a put-item into the table when inserting the item would retain the uniqueness of the hash key and one other table attribute.

It seems simple enough to define the condition expression to be as shown below, but it doesn't work.

My question is how can I make put-item conditional on two attributes being separately unique in the table?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TABLE_NAME="Test"

read -r -d '' ATTRIBUTE_DEFINITIONS << EOF
[
  {
    "AttributeName": "hashKey",
    "AttributeType": "S"
  }
]
EOF

read -r -d '' KEY_SCHEMA << EOF
{
  "AttributeName": "hashKey",
  "KeyType":       "HASH"
}
EOF

read -r -d '' THROUGHPUT << EOF
{
  "ReadCapacityUnits":  1,
  "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
}
EOF

read -r -d '' ITEM1 << EOF
{
  "hashKey": { "S": "one" },
  "blah":    { "S": "foo" }
}
EOF

read -r -d '' ITEM2 << EOF
{
  "hashKey": { "S": "one" },
  "blah":    { "S": "baz" }
}
EOF

read -r -d '' ITEM3 << EOF
{
  "hashKey": { "S": "two" },
  "blah":    { "S": "baz" }
}
EOF

CONDEXP="hashKey<>:hk AND blah<>:bh"

read -r -d '' EXPVALUES2 << EOF
{
  ":hk": { "S": "two" },
  ":bh": { "S": "baz" }
}
EOF

read -r -d '' EXPVALUES3 << EOF
{
  ":hk": { "S": "two" },
  ":bh": { "S": "baz" }
}
EOF

aws dynamodb create-table                          \
  --table-name "$TABLE_NAME"                       \
  --attribute-definitions "$ATTRIBUTE_DEFINITIONS" \
  --key-schema "$KEY_SCHEMA"                       \
  --provisioned-throughput "$THROUGHPUT" 

aws dynamodb put-item                              \
  --table-name "$TABLE_NAME"                       \
  --item "$ITEM1"

# BUG: I want this this fail because the hashKey in
# ITEM2 is already in the table. It doesn't fail
aws dynamodb put-item                              \
  --table-name "$TABLE_NAME"                       \
  --item "$ITEM2"                                  \
  --condition-expression "$CONDEXP"                \
  --expression-attribute-values "$EXPVALUES2"

# BUG: I want this this fail because the blah in
# ITEM3 is already in the table
aws dynamodb put-item                              \
  --table-name "$TABLE_NAME"                       \
  --item "$ITEM3"                                  \
  --condition-expression "$CONDEXP"                \
  --expression-attribute-values "$EXPVALUES3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition expressions only work within the context of one item. Uniqueness of an attribute is a table-global property. While you can condition a write (Put/Update/Delete Item) on the non-existence of a key using attribute_not_exists(hk), the table will not ensure uniqueness of other attributes by itself. You could enable a [Stream](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) on the table and [attach a Lambda function](http://dynamodb-preview.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/docs/streams-dg/Streams.Lambda.Walkthrough.Basic.html) to the stream that populates a materialized view keyed on your second attribute bh and check the materialized view for bh uniqueness and then by doing a conditional write on the base table. NB, there is a race condition between the materialized view bh check and the conditional write to base table in this approach that you may have to address, depending on your application.